# thread::hardware_concurrency() checking returns zero value

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I'm using RHEL 6 64-bit and run on Virtual Machine on quad-core processors. I wrote the following program to examine the number of threads the hardware can handle.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << thread::hardware_concurrency() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is always zero, what is the reason of such result?

Answer (score 2):

from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency):

> Returns the number of concurrent threads supported by the
>   implementation. The value should be considered only a hint.

and also :

> **Return value**
>
> number of concurrent threads supported. If the value is not well
>   defined or not computable, returns ​0​.

so `thread::hardware_concurrency()` doesn't have to give you anything accurate. 
"accurate" is also in the eyes of the beholder. If I have two cores which support hyper-threading, should `hardware_concurrency` return `2` or `4`?