# Determine how many times each character occurs in a file through multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

My code. I wrote that I could. Now your help is needed. Tell me
what is wrong. And how do I shield as many times as I have a symbol? I do not know how to do it properly, I read books. but still nothing works out

```
void TextThread(std::string str)
{
  std::ifstream text(str);
  if (!text)
    std::cout << "No open file" << "\n";

  std::istream_iterator<char> input(text);
  std::istream_iterator<char> output;

  std::vector<char> symvol(input, output);

  unsigned maxThreadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  const std::size_t minLength = symvol.size() / maxThreadCount;
  const std::size_t modulo = symvol.size() % maxThreadCount;

  std::vector<std::size_t> results;
  results.reserve(maxThreadCount);

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  threads.reserve(maxThreadCount - 1);

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < modulo; ++i)
    results.emplace_back(minLength + 1);

  if (minLength > 0)
  {
     for (std::size_t i = modulo; i < maxThreadCount; ++i)
        results.emplace_back(minLength);
  }
  for (std::size_t i = 1; i < threads.size(); ++i)
    threads.emplace_back(threads[i - 1] + 1, threads[i - 1] + threads[i]);

  std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), 
   std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));


  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < symvol.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << symvol[i] << "\n";
}


int main()
{
  TextThread("D:\\text.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

UPD: 
I'll display all the characters on the screen

```
void TextThread(std::string str)
 {
   std::ifstream text(str);
   if (!text)
    std::cout << "No open file" << "\n";

  std::istream_iterator<char> input(text);
  std::istream_iterator<char> output;

  std::vector<char> symvol(input, output);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < symvol.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << symvol[i] << "\n";
 }
```

UPD2:

Do it like you. It remains to do with multithreading

```
 using Symbol = std::array<size_t, 256>;
 Symbol  CountSymbol(std::vector<char> const& data) 
 {
    Symbol countSymbol{};
    for (unsigned char ch : data) 
        countSymbol[ch] += 1;
    return countSymbol;
 }


 Symbol SymbolFile(std::string const& fname) 
 {
   std::ifstream text(fname);

   if (!text)
      throw std::runtime_error("No open file");

   std::vector<char> const data(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{text}, {});
     return CountSymbol(data);
 }

 int main() 
 {
    Symbol  symbol = SymbolFile("D:\\text.txt");
    for (int ch = 0; ch <= 255; ++ch) 
    {
       if (symbol[ch]) 
       {
           if (std::isprint(ch))
            std::cout << "Character '" << char(ch) << "' occurs " << 
        symbol[ch] << " times\n";
           else
               std::cout << "Character #" << ch << " occurs " << symbol[ch] 
        << " times\n";
       }
    }
}
```

UPD3

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include <thread>
 #include <cctype>
 #include <clocale>
 #include <numeric>

 std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> GenerateIntervals(const 
       std::vector<char>& text)
 {
     std::size_t maxThreadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
     const std::size_t minLength = text.size() / maxThreadCount;
     const std::size_t modulo = text.size() % maxThreadCount;

     std::vector<std::size_t> intervalLengthPerThread;
     intervalLengthPerThread.reserve(maxThreadCount);

     for (std::size_t i = 0; i < modulo; ++i)
    intervalLengthPerThread.emplace_back(minLength + 1);

if (minLength > 0)
{
    for (std::size_t i = modulo; i < maxThreadCount; ++i)
        intervalLengthPerThread.emplace_back(minLength);
}

std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> intervals;
intervals.reserve(intervalLengthPerThread.size());

intervals.emplace_back(0, 0 + intervalLengthPerThread[0] - 1);
for (std::size_t i = 1; i < intervalLengthPerThread.size(); ++i)
    intervals.emplace_back(intervals[i - 1].second + 1, intervals[i - 1].second + intervalLengthPerThread[i]);

return intervals;
}

 void BuildHistogram(const std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>& textRange, 
 const std::vector<char>& text, std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t>& 
  histogram)
 {
    for (std::size_t i = textRange.first; i < textRange.second; ++i) 
        ++histogram[text[i]];
 }

 std::vector<char> ReadDataFromFile(const std::string& pathToFile)
{
std::ifstream stream(pathToFile);

if (!stream) 
{
    std::vector<char> result;
    std::cout << "Can not open file" << "\n";
    return result;
}

std::istream_iterator<char> it(stream);
std::istream_iterator<char> itEnd;

std::vector<char> text(it, itEnd);
}

 int main() 
 {
auto text = ReadDataFromFile("D:\\text.txt");

const auto textIntervals = GenerateIntervals(text);
const auto usedThreadCount = textIntervals.size();

std::vector<std::unordered_map<char, size_t>> histograms(usedThreadCount);
std::vector<std::thread> threads(usedThreadCount);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < usedThreadCount; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(BuildHistogram, std::cref(textIntervals[i]), text, std::ref(histograms[i]));

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < usedThreadCount; ++i)
    threads[i].join();

std::unordered_map<char, size_t> histogram;
for (const auto& hist : histograms)
{
    for (const auto& pair : hist)
        histogram[pair.first] += pair.second;
}

for (int ch = 0; ch < 256; ++ch) 
{
    if (text[ch]) 
    {
        std::cout << "Character '" << char(ch) << "' occurs " << text[ch] << " times\n";
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean when you say "how do I shield"? Also, you don't start any threads, as far as I can see.

Comment: So tempting to write bogosort applied to histogramming

Comment: @igagis `threads.emplace_back`

Comment: @igagis I need to count how many times each character is found in the file. That's what I meant. how do i calculate how many times a sim is found

Comment: What function do you intend to run on the thread... Currently you're just trying to magically "summon" threads passing indices to it. That's... not what a thread does. A thread runs _code_. You'll have to think decide _what_ code, and _then_ pass those arguments to _it_.

Comment: Also, do you intend to skip all whitespace? Because you skip all whitespace now.

Comment: @igagis I start any threads - std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), 
   std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець That's the join part though. You don't start any threads (though I can see where you "dream of" starting them)

Comment: @sehe Can you write an example code how to properly run to work the program? I'm suffering for 2 days and I can not write (confused, I do not understand anything ...)

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, try launching some simple thread first, don't jump into complicated stuff right off the bat. Come [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers). Ping me when you're there.

Comment: @Incomputable did, easy examples all ok works. And here I am confused what is wrong. If it is not difficult to write: here it is not correct, so it is necessary to do .... and here it is not correct - so it is necessary to do.

Comment: Can you share the easy example that works? It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to achieve (in the end, you just print all chars in symvol?)

Comment: I can not write in chat. as there is no reputation

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, threads only accept callable objects, like functions and lambdas. You're passing threads again. It is not correct.

Comment: @sehe Posted in UPD

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець The code in the update only prints all non-whitespace characters (very inefficiently). Adding threads to that makes everything even more inefficient, and still does nothing that resembles "Determine how many times each character occurs in a file through multithreading
"

Comment: @sehe I just need to put the lab on the subject. I do not learn about the programmer and I understand that is a weird task, but I have to do it. So if you do not have a hard time, can you write an example on which I can do the job? Or just write how to add to my UPD code a lot of streaming and I'll be very grateful to you.

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, if you're not interested in learning, then you came to the wrong place.

Comment: @Incomputable I'm interested in learning !! I posted my code that I wrote. And asked to say that is not correct. And I do not mean anything to your general expressions, I need to specifically write-this part of the code is not correct-you need to (lead example). and then - functions and lambda. You're passing threads again. - I did not help anything. I did not know what wrong and I do not know (((

Comment: Calm down. We're trying to help. Acting desperate does not help you understand. We know you're desperate. That's ok. We've all learned.

Comment: if you need to do flows in another function, no problem. but why do you need to do it?

Comment: @sehe ok. I see). Let's then parse my code to disassemble and say what's wrong there and how better.

Comment: If you are with the answer you may want to accept it, if you have follow up errors, you may consider to open another topic here:)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be helpful here, because you're very lost.

### The Goal

I **think** you want a histogram, so like:

```
std::array<size_t, 256> histo;
```

Here, every element corresponds to the integral value of the input character (say, `a` is 97).

Here's the straightforward implementation:

```
using Histo = std::array<size_t, 256>;

Histo histogram(std::vector<char> const& data) {
    Histo histo {}; // value initialize, makes sure all elements are 0

    for (auto ch : data) {
        histo[ch] += 1;
    }

    return histo;
}
```

> **Note** There's a very subtle thing here where I convert the character to `unsigned char` (could also say `uint8_t`). This is because some platforms will have `char` be signed and that leads to errors when indexing `histo[ch]` or when comparing (e.g. `ch <= 255` would always be true).

And you could operate on the contents of a file like this:

```
Histo histogram_file(std::string const& fname) {
    std::ifstream text(fname);

    if (!text)
        throw std::runtime_error("No open file");

    std::vector<char> const data(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{text}, {});
    return histogram(data);
}
```

> **Note** The use of `istreambuf_iterator` does **not** skip whitespace (as `istreambuf_iterator` does by default, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws).

### Live Demo

Simple code **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd0751f506bde98f)</kbd>**

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using Histo = std::array<size_t, 256>;

Histo histogram(std::vector<char> const& data) {
    Histo histo {}; // value initialize, makes sure all elements are 0

    for (unsigned char ch : data) {
        histo[ch] += 1;
    }

    return histo;
}


Histo histogram_file(std::string const& fname) {
    std::ifstream text(fname);

    if (!text)
        throw std::runtime_error("No open file");

    std::vector<char> const data(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{text}, {});
    return histogram(data);
}

int main() {
    Histo histo = histogram_file("main.cpp");
    for (int ch = 0; ch <= 255; ++ch) {
        if (histo[ch]) {
            if (std::isprint(ch))
                std::cout << "Character '" << char(ch) << "' occurs " << histo[ch] << " times\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Character #" << ch << " occurs " << histo[ch] << " times\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints something like

```
Character #10 occurs 41 times
Character ' ' occurs 224 times
Character '!' occurs 1 times
Character '"' occurs 16 times
Character '#' occurs 7 times
...
Character 'x' occurs 3 times
Character 'y' occurs 1 times
Character 'z' occurs 2 times
Character '{' occurs 9 times
Character '}' occurs 9 times
```

### Making It Threaded

To distribute the work, we'll have to call `histogram` for a part of the vector data. Let's modify our function slightly to achieve that:

```
template <typename Iterator> // could just use `char const*` but let's not
Histo histogram(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    Histo histo {}; // value initialize, makes sure all elements are 0

    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        histo[*it] += 1;
    }

    return histo;
}

Histo histogram(std::vector<char> const& data) {
    return histogram(data.begin(), data.end());
}
```

As you can see, we can forward the "old" signature right to the new, more flexible interface. Of course you could get finicky with `char const*` directly and have exactly the same code, but it would not work as well if the input were anything different from a vector. Or if it became a `std::deque<unsigned char>` etc.

## Doing The Concurrency

We want to divide work in equal chunks:

```
using It = std::vector<char>::const_iterator;

// calculate chunk size
auto chunk = data.size() / num_threads;
if (chunk*num_threads < data.size()) chunk += 1;
```

> Note that the last chunk could be extend (

Because you can't (usefully) share the `Histo` object between all the threads (the cost of synchronizing access would far outweigh any speed benefit of concurrent processing), we have to have `Histo` with each thread.

Let's do it clumsy and manual first:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
// start chunk threads
struct worker_t {
    Histo local; // histogram per thread
    std::thread th;

    void run(It begin, It end) {
        local = histogram(begin, end);
    }
};
std::vector<worker_t> workers(num_threads);
```

Now we can just start `run` on each worker instance, passing the calculated subrange:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto& w : workers) {
    auto begin = data.begin()+chunk*i,
         end   = std::min(begin + chunk, data.end());
    w.th = std::thread(&worker_t::run, std::ref(w), begin, end);
    ++i;
}
```

#### Waiting And Merging

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
// wait for completion
for (auto& w : workers) {
    if (w.th.joinable())
        w.th.join();
};
```

This is almost what you already had.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
// merge results
Histo histo;
for (auto& w : workers) {
    merge_into(histo, w.local);
}

return histo;
```

Note the habit of writing the code you want to read, and then implementing more detail. In this case, we have still define `merge_into`:

```
void merge_into(Histo& into, Histo const& part) {
    for (auto& p : part)
        into[p.first] += p.second;
}
```

#### Manual Workers Demo

The above **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6bfa0d6e8e6c36c)</kbd>** and **<kbd>[MSVC on RexTester](http://rextester.com/YWCF74637)</kbd>**

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

using Histo = std::map<char, size_t>;

void merge_into(Histo& into, Histo const& part) {
    for (auto& p : part)
        into[p.first] += p.second;
}

template <typename Iterator> // could just use `char const*` but let's not
Histo histogram(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    Histo histo {}; // value initialize, makes sure all elements are 0

    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        histo[*it] += 1;
    }

    return histo;
}

Histo histogram(std::vector<char> const& data) {
    return histogram(data.begin(), data.end());
}

Histo parallel_histo(std::vector<char> const& data, size_t num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) {
    using It = std::vector<char>::const_iterator;

    // calculate chunk size
    auto chunk = data.size() / num_threads;
    if (chunk*num_threads < data.size()) chunk += 1;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // start chunk threads
    struct worker_t {
        Histo local; // histogram per thread
        std::thread th;

        void run(It begin, It end) {
            local = histogram(begin, end);
        }
    };
    std::vector<worker_t> workers(num_threads);

    int i = 0;
    for (auto& w : workers) {
        auto begin = data.begin()+chunk*i,
             end   = std::min(begin + chunk, data.end());
        w.th = std::thread(&worker_t::run, std::ref(w), begin, end);
        ++i;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // wait for completion
    for (auto& w : workers) {
        if (w.th.joinable())
            w.th.join();
    };

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // merge results
    Histo histo;
    for (auto& w : workers) {
        merge_into(histo, w.local);
    }

    return histo;
}

Histo histogram_file(std::string const& fname) {
    std::ifstream text(fname);

    if (!text)
        throw std::runtime_error("No open file");

    return parallel_histo({std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{text}, {}});
}

int main() {
    Histo histo = histogram_file("main.cpp");
    for (int ch = 0; ch <= 255; ++ch) {
        if (histo[ch]) {
            if (std::isprint(ch))
                std::cout << "Character '" << char(ch) << "' occurs " << histo[ch] << " times\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Character #" << ch << " occurs " << histo[ch] << " times\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints the same output as before.

### Less Clumsy

The "standard-library" to divy up tasks that take input and generate results is to use `std::async` which can simply return results. It's not perfect, but it is a whole lot less work:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4d6d1fba3d6fb43)</kbd>**

```
Histo parallel_histo(std::vector<char> const& data, size_t num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) {
    // calculate chunk size
    auto chunk = data.size() / num_threads;
    if (chunk*num_threads < data.size()) chunk += 1;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // start tasks
    std::vector<std::future<Histo> > tasks(num_threads);

    int i = 0;
    for (auto& t : tasks) {
        auto begin = data.begin()+chunk*i,
             end   = std::min(begin + chunk, data.end());

        t = std::async([=,&data] { return histogram(begin, end); });
    }

    Histo histo;
    for (auto& t : tasks) {
        merge_into(histo, t.get());
    }

    return histo;
}
```

### Zen Master

Of course, if you really know the standard library you will use it (c++17):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>

using Histo = std::vector<std::atomic_size_t>;

Histo histogram(std::vector<char> const& data) {
    Histo histo(256);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, data.begin(), data.end(), [&histo](unsigned char ch) { ++histo[ch]; });
    return histo;
}

Histo histogram_file(std::string const& fname) {
    std::ifstream text(fname);

    if (!text)
        throw std::runtime_error("No open file");

    return histogram({std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{text}, {}});
}
```

Sadly you can't use this yet, as no compiler vendor actually (fully) implements it.

Comment: I'll be back shortly. Family needs attention

Comment: why are you doing for in main? So it is better to do?

Comment: First things first. So, I guessed the purpose of the task correctly (why wasn't that in your code?) And now suddenly you chose `unordered_map`. Why? Also, **names** are incredibly important. Don't (ever) call your function `TextThread`. It has nothing to with threads and `Text` doesn't describe what it does. What it does is 1. read a file 2. create  a histogram (likewise, don't call your function `ValueSymbol` if it doesn't value symbols. It makes a histogram. So, `create_histogram`, `histogram`, `histo`, `tally_frequencies`, maybe even `count_occurrences`. But, never `ValueSymbol`.

Comment: Same for `str`. If it's a filename, call it `file_specification` or `fname`. NEVER call a string variable `str` unless that's the only relevant thing you know about it (`std::string trim(std::string const& str);` could be ok, for example)

Comment: Note also, good structure means it is literally one line change in my code to [use `std::map`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2857e579e2341e57) or [use `std::unordered_map`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db0d1f642c74a8e0).

Comment: Excuse me, do you think I haven't seen your question? I'm not **required** to answer your question. And as it happens, I'm answering it, but answering it takes time. I don't really do half-assed answers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I just did not quit multithreading)) And I just asked about multithreading. Thank you for showing how to count symbols.I am very grateful to you for helping and not turning away from me

Comment: I know I'm not done... sigh. It would be easier if your question made sense to begin with. You **cannot** "just ask about multithreading" when the code is such a mess that it doesn't do anything useful. There's no way can "answer" that, beyong pointing to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread. It's really not nice to repeat the question just because you don't understand things/are afraid we won't explain. If that happens, it happens: you are not "buying" answers, so you might not get all the answers you need. So, next time, just be patient. (The answer is complete now).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Is `256` intended to be `UCHAR_MAX + 1`?  Please don't encourage non-portable assumptions!

Comment: @sehe Error^ Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2660 'parallel_histo': function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: return parallel_histo({std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{text}, {}});

Comment: Now : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець does this help http://rextester.com/YWCF74637 (more includes, protecting `std::min` and using `std::bind`. Note I've fixed a bug (`++i;`))

Comment: @sehe Good day. I wrote all the same the same program(UPD3). You can see the implementation and say that you do not like it. If there are many remarks then I'll take your version of the program and everything. thank you

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець are you sure your code works? `ReadDataFromFile` doesn't return a value. Why do you do `GenerateIntervals` separately? That just wastes more resources (allocating a multiple vectors...). You should use typedefs (`using Histo = std::map<char, size_t>;` instead of  repeating unwieldy types like `std::unordered_map<char, size_t>` all over). `textIntervals`, `threads` and `histograms` are parallel vectors - that's an enormous antipattern. Structured data exists. When the file doesn't exist, you treat it as an empty file?

Comment: Thanks for the post! What if `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` returns 0?

Comment: @Yola in that case is say you have nothing to worry about. Of you have no CPU the performance will be exactly the same regardless of whether you multi thread it.

Comment: From the Standard *If the value is not well defined or not computable, returns ​0​*` You mean that can't ever happen?

Comment: @Yola excellent point, I was [very surprised by this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37000757/85371). Yes, by all means if the code is to run on untested platforms, guard against degenerate `hardware_concurrency()` implementations! Thanks for making me aware of this.